# issue with importing android.support.test.*

Tags: java, android, android-espresso

I add this **dependencies to gradle:**

// Unit testing dependencies

```
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

// Set this dependency if you want to use the Hamcrest matcher library

```
testCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3'
```

// more stuff, e.g., Mockito

```
androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.+'
androidTestCompile "com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.2"
androidTestCompile "com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.2"

androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.3'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.3'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2'
```

// add this for intent mocking support

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:2.2'
```

// add this for webview testing support

```
 androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-web:2.2'
```

and sync build.gradle successfully but when i want to import this classes :

```
import static android.support.test.espresso.Espresso.onView;
import static android.support.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.click;
import static android.support.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions.matches;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withId;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withText;
```

the IDE (Android Studio 1.2) give me an error that  Cannot resolve symbol test , I search too much and I didn't find any answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found whats my fault , in AndroidStudio go to file/settings/compiler and uncheck the Use-in-process build then test will work

Comment: There is not such option in Android Studio 1.4 Preview 3

Comment: It is back in 1.5, but it didn't help for me